# Checking last file modified time in C on Windows as a non-admin

Tags: c++, c, windows, permissions, stat

I am writing a C/C++ application where I need to compare the last modified times of two files, one in an installation directory (i.e. owned by SYSTEM and with wrx permissions for SYSTEM/admins and no one else) and one in user-writable space.  I tried using the C function stat(filename,&st) to check for the last modified time, but it only found the correct time for the file in the installation directory when the program was run as an administrator.  It is my understanding that stat need execution privileges in the directory in order to run.

So, in C/C++, how does a non-admin determine the last modified time of a file in an installation directory?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that stat was actually working, but instead of looking at the file in the installation directory, it was actually looking at the file in

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\

which was an older file.  When the program was run as an administrator, it looked in the actual directory.  I was able to solve my problem by deleting the files in the VirtualStore.

Another workaround was to launch a system process to run stat at the command line.  I was able to access the file directly with stat in that way, whereas using stat in the source code caused Windows to redirect to the VirtualStore version of the file.

Comment: The path that I entered was edited.  There should be the user name between Users and AppData, and the installation path of the program after VirtualStore.

Comment: I believe that if your application has a manifest indicating that it is Vista-compatible, Windows will not redirect file access to the virtual store.  I'm not certain.